# Img with .ico extension gets distorted on Chrome while It works fine on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on an application where we allow users to upload any image to use inside the Web. however whenever the user uploads an image with a `.ico` extension it gets blurred up on **Chrome** while it works fine on **Firefox**.

The only style applied to the image is:

`img{
width:100%;
}`

Please try the attached Codepen on Chrome and Firefox:

https://codepen.io/zeeshanadilbutt/pen/jpQgKO

Is this a chrome bug? what can be the optimal solution for this?

Comment: That ico contains 6 PNG images of different sizes, evidently the browsers differ in selecting which one to display, that's likely a decision you need to make by extracting the correct image based on whatever criteria are appropriate.

Comment: Different browsers use different rendering engines to render favicons and each have a recommended size for fav icons. If you adjust your image to 196x196 it actually looks fine in chrome. If you search favicon cheat sheet you might find more information to help you.

Comment: @AlexK. and how can I do that? like how can I extract the image in right proportion to display there?

Comment: @scrappedcola I understand but unfortunately we need images with 100% width